# Get XML tag and attribute upto n level

Tags: php, xml

Is it possible to get tag names and attributes names with values upto n levels.
For example,

File 1:

```
<?xml ?>
<data>
    <student>
        <std>4th</std>
        <student>Alex</student>
        <division name="A" />
    </student>
</data>
```

File 2:

```
<?xml ?>
<data>
    <students>
        <student>
            <std>4th</std>
            <student>Alex</student>
            <division name="A" />
        </student>
        <student>
            <std>5th</std>
            <student>Alice</student>
            <division name="D" />
            <subject>Drawing</subject>
        </student>
    </students>
</data>
```

File 3:

```
<?xml ?>
<data>
    <students>
        <student>
            <std>4th</std>
            <student>Alex</student>
            <division name="A" />
        </student>
        <student>
            <std>5th</std>
            <student>Alice</student>
            <division name="D" />
            <subject>Drawing</subject>
        </student>
    </students>
    <students>
        <student>
            <std>4th</std>
            <student>Alex</student>
        </student>
        <student>
            <std>5th</std>
            <student>Alice</student>
            <division name="D" />
            <subject>Drawing</subject>
        </student>
        <student>
            <std>5th</std>
            <student>Alice</student>
            <division name="D" />
            <subject>
                <sub1>Drwaing</sub1>
                <sub1>Maths</sub1>
            </subject>
        </student>
    </students>
</data>
```

Above are examples file 1 is simple file, file 2 is with more tags and file 3 is more longer than other. So my basic question is that XML file format is not predefined it's may be anything just like above examples. So is it possible to get tags names, attribute names with its values in php? If yes then how?

I already tried some solutions with `$xml->children()->children()` and `$child->getName()` i didn't find any perfect way normally it is good for 2 level or 3 level but no solution for **N** level xml tags.

I tried as below :

```
$xml='<person>
    <child role="son">
        <child role="daughter"/>
    </child>
    <child role="daughter">
        <child role="son">
            <child role="son"/>
            <name role="trainer">
                <nickname role="assistant">Nic</nickname>
                <fname>Nicolas</fname>
                <lname>Johnson</lname>
                <hobby>
                    <sport>
                        <game>
                            <name>Cricket</name>
                            <name type="male">Hockey</name>
                            <name type="national" />
                        </game>
                    </sport>
                </hobby>
            </name>
        </child>
    </child>
    <child role="daughter">
        <child role="son">
            <child role="son"/>
            <name role="student">Jessika</name>
        </child>
        <child role="son">
            <child role="son"/>
            <names>
                <name>Nick</name>
            </names>
        </child>
    </child>
    <child role="daughter">
        <child role="son">
            <child role="son"/>
        </child>
        <child role="son">
            <child role="son"/>
            <child role="son"/>
            <name>Tom</name>
        </child>
        <child role="son">
            <child role="son"/>
            <child role="son"/>
            <name>John</name>
        </child>
    </child>
</person>';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
foreach ($xml->children() as $second_gen) {
    echo '<br> role=' . $second_gen['role'];
    foreach ($second_gen->children() as $third_gen) {
        echo '<br> role=' . $third_gen['role'];
        foreach ($third_gen->children() as $fourth_gen) {
            echo '<br> role=' . $third_gen['role'];
        }
    }
}
```

Note that file1, file2 & file3 example are different and above are different so don't confused i already mentioned that XML file & format are not predefined it may be anything any level.

In above example i tried with 3 foreach loops but when it is upto **N** level then it's not working properly. I want to do totally dynamically. Is it possible?

If you have more better ideas or ways then you can share. Thanks for giving your valuable time.

**I want to do following.**

I want to get some values like student name, fees, standard, stream, subjects, division and other normal details from XML. Now the main problem is XML format is not predefined it may be like as above examples that i mentioned. It is totally dynamic and i want to store in table as per the tags and/or attribute values.

I hope are useful to understand what i want to say if any doubts then feel free to ask. Thanks.

Comment: You said you already tried "some solutions". Can you post those solutions?

Comment: What output are you trying to get?

Comment: I want to get each tag name and it's attribute name so i can get it's values if exists. And store it to table. I don't have brief knowledge regarding so i am confused is it possible or not?

Comment: *is it possible or not* - yes it is.  BUT unless you give a good example of what you want out of this (i.e. give an example using 1 file and what it should do - what database table it would populate, is it dynamic etc.) it's difficult to give a good solution.

Comment: Updated as above

Answer (score 0):

Xpath expressions allow you to fetch nodes (and values) from the XML document.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<data>
    <student>
        <std>4th</std>
        <student>Alex</student>
        <division name="A" />
    </student>
</data>
XML;

$data = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

foreach($data->xpath('//student[student]') as $student) {
  var_dump(
    [
      (string)$student->std,
      (string)$student->student,
      (string)$student->division['name']
    ]
  );
}
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=> 
  string(3) "4th"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "Alex"
  [2]=> 
  string(1) "A" 
}
```

#### The Xpath Expression

- any `student` element node in the document...
  `//student`
- ... that has a `student` child element:
  `//student[student]`

Xpath expressions are quite powerful. For example you could fetch any `student` that has no `student` ancestor node, too:

`//student[not(ancestor::student)]`